# VBA: adding blank rows above a value based upon criteria

Tags: excel, vba

So I had a complex earlier question, but Ive simplified the problem quite a bit:

Short version after some other vba runs, I have a column, numbered, 10, 20, 30, 40, ect. as an index,  at certain points, the number will restart

So what I want to do is start from the top , identify the 10's and then insert a number of blank rows in order to keep the row# consistent as if there were rows numbered 1-10.

example input would be:

```
 1. 10     someotherdata
 2. 20     someotherdata
 3. 30     someotherdata
 5. 10     someotherdata
 6. 20     someotherdata
 7. 30     someotherdata
ect.
```

output would be (7 rows inserted to get the next sequence to start at row 11)

```
 1. 10     someotherdata
 2. 20     someotherdata
 3. 30     someotherdata
 4. Blank
 5. Blank
 6. Blank
 7. Blank
 8. Blank
 9. Blank
 10. Blank
 11. 10     someotherdata
 12. 20     someotherdata
 13. 30     someotherdata
```

TL:DR
-find a 10
-check the row above it for a value (in this case 30)
10 - (30/10) = 7
-insert 7 rows between the 10 and 30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `for` loop for this task. But I'd suggest starting from the last row of the list to the second from the top (from bottom to top). This way, there won't be troubles with rows shifting and the variable holding current row number being processed. Something like the code below (I don't have access to Excel at the moment to check how it works):

```
For r=lastRow To 2 Step -1
  If Cells(r, col).value = 10 Then
    nRows = 10 - Cells(r-1, col).Value / 10 ' number of rows to insert
    Cells(r, col).Resize(nRows, 1).Insert xlShiftDown
  End If
Next r
```

Comment: this worked great, just had to adjust the code a little, the final version was:

'
For r = 100 To 2 Step -1
  If Cells(r, 14).Value = 10 Then
    nRows = 10 - Cells(r - 1, 14).Value / 10 ' number of rows to insert
    Cells(r, 1).Resize(nRows, 14).Insert xlShiftDown
  End If
Next r'